# Are these "finite-ish" sets closed under union?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, axiom-of-choice

*Now [asked at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376011/is-this-notion-of-finiteness-closed-under-unions).*

Throughout, we work in $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Say that a set $X$ is $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite if for every first-order sentence $\varphi$, if $\varphi$ has a model with underlying set $X$ then $\varphi$ has a finite model. *(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3765978/28111), and the answer and comments, for background.)* Every $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite set is Dedekind-finite basically trivially, and with some model theory we can show that every amorphous set is $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite. Beyond that, however, things are less clear.

In particular, I noticed that I can't seem to prove a very basic property of this notion:

> Is the union of two $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite sets always $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite?

I'm probably missing something simple, but I don't see a good way to get a handle on this. A structure on $X=A\sqcup B$ might not "see" that partition at all, and so none of the simple tricks I can think of work.

Comment: I mean, where does the proof that $\Pi^1_1$ is closed under conjunctions fail?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't see how that helps. Suppose there's a way to give $A\sqcup B$ the structure of a model of $\varphi$ where $\varphi$ has no finite models. How do I get any sort of structure on $A$ or $B$?

Comment: Right. How about the union of two amorphous sets, is it $\Pi^1_1$-p.f.?

Comment: @AsafKaragila No idea! Seriously this is embarrassing as all heck.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvote? (It's totally possible I'm missing something obvious, but [I wouldn't seem to be alone in that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376011/is-this-notion-of-finiteness-closed-under-unions).)

Comment: The union of two amorphous sets is something we can detect, in principle, since up to finite error, there's only one partition with more than one infinite set (and in general, the union of $n$ amorphous sets will have a maximal partition, up to finite mistakes). Either that, or the result is amorphous because the two sets were equal up to a finite part.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh that's a nice observation. I don't see how to use that here, though - do you?

Comment: No. I don't really have any intuition about any of this, to be honest. (I'll point out that I made that observation on the MO thread back then, it just went unnoticed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move this off the unanswered queue, I'll mention here that Harry West [gave a negative answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/396101/8133) to this question at MO. (I've made this CW to avoid reputation gain.)