# In ZF, if injection from A to B doesn't exist, then does surjection from A to B exist?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Claim : For non-empty sets $A, B$, (if there's no injection from $A$ to $B$, then there exists a surjection from $A$ to $B$.)

I wonder how to prove or disprove that the 1st(2nd)-order logic sentence is generally true in ZF.

That claim is true in ZFC, since we can well-order both A and B, so A and B have cardinalities, the class of cardinalities are linearly ordered by inclusion. So, the claim isn't generally false in ZF.

The converse is false in ZF, since both surjection and injection can exist between the same set A.
And the similar sentence : for non-empty sets A and B, (if there exists a surjection from A to B, then there exists injection from B to A.),  is independent about ZF.

I guess the claim isn't generally true in ZF, and I tried to deduce the sentence which is independent about ZF, but not yet succeeded.
Also, I couldn't construct a model of ZF where the counter example exists.

How can I prove or disprove the claim is independent about ZF?

Comment: "Also, I couldn't construct a model of ZF where the counter example exists." It turns out to be **incredibly difficult** to construct models of $\mathsf{ZF}+\neg\mathsf{AC}$ at all, in fact, so you shouldn't feel discouraged here - it's a serious task!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, this statement is equivalent to the axiom of choice.  Given a nonempty set $B$, let $A$ be its Hartogs number, the least ordinal that does not inject into $B$.  Then, by your assumption, there must be a surjection $f:A\to B$.  But since $A$ is well-ordered, we can use this to construct an injection $g:B\to A$, by letting $g(b)$ be the least $a$ such that $f(a)=b$.  This gives a well-ordering of $B$.

Comment: +1. To the OP, note that the existence of Hartogs numbers does **not** require choice: $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that for every set $X$, there is a (unique) smallest ordinal $\alpha$ which does not inject into $X$. This isn't actually trivial, and is a good exercise.

Comment: @Noah: Sadly, I seem to have lost my old Math 771 notes — it *has* been 49 years — but I think that Ken actually did assign that theorem as one of our regular homework problems.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and concept. 
I haven't thought that this would be equivalent to the AoC.

Comment: (Incidentally, Eric may not remember this but he was the one who gave *me* this exercise - way back 15 years ago at a summer camp! It was the first "technical" set theory argument I ever saw.)

Answer (score 7):

Let $A$ be an [amorphous set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set); then there is no injection from $\Bbb N$ to $A$, and there is no surjection from $\Bbb N$ to $A$.

Let $f:\Bbb N\to A$. If $f$ were injective, then $A_0=\{f(2n):n\in\Bbb N\}$ and $A\setminus A_0$ would be disjoint infinite subsets of $A$ whose union is $A$, which is impossible, since $A$ is amorphous. And if $f$ were surjective, the function

$$h:A\to\Bbb N:a\mapsto\min\{n\in\Bbb N:f(n)=a\}$$

would be a bijection from $A$ to the infinite set $M=h[A]\subseteq\Bbb N$. If $\varphi:\Bbb N\to M$ is the canonical order-isomorphism, $h^{-1}\circ\varphi$ would be a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $A$, which again is impossible.

Comment: More generally, $\mathbb{N}$ isn't comparable with any infinite Dedekind-finite set.

Comment: @Noah: Yes, I did grab a heftier club than I really needed, didn’t I.

Comment: Holy what. TIL amorphous sets. My poor mind does not like this at all. There's a reason I'm an analyst and not a set theorist..

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Must be dual to the reason that I’m a set-theoretic topologist and not an analyst. :-)

Comment: I haven't heard the amorphous set concepts.  Pretty interesting. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @정재우: You’re welcome; I know only the basics about them, but I also find them quite interesting.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Amorphous sets are **awesome**! I think they become a lot more acceptable once you start thinking in terms of sets as potential carriers of interesting structure; the absence of choice allows us to consider sets which can carry some types of structure but not others (in a way which is ruled out by choice), and amorphous sets constitute an extreme behavior of this type - see e.g. the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765978/the-complexity-of-finiteness) (apologies for blatant self-promotion).