Is ordinalhood (sans $\mathsf{AF}$) $\Delta_1$?
Is the formula defining $\alpha$ to be an ordinal $\Delta_1$ in $\mathsf{ZF}^-$? An ordinal is defined to be any transitive set wherein $\in$ is strictly wellordered, i.e., $\alpha \in On \equiv (\forall x \in \alpha) \ (\forall y \in x) \ (y \in \alpha) \land (\forall x \in \alpha) \ (x \notin x) \land (\forall x, y, z \in \alpha) \ (x \in y \land y \in z \Rightarrow x \in z) \land (\forall X \subseteq \alpha) \ (X \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow (\exists x \in X) \ (\forall y \in X) \ (x \in y \lor y = x))$.
Given the reference to "$X \subseteq \alpha$," such becomes (as I understand it) a $\Pi_1$ formula.
If we assume $\mathsf{AF}$, $\in$ is already wellfounded under any set $\alpha$, hence an ordinal is just any transitive set wherein $\in$ is connected, i.e., $\alpha \in On \equiv (\forall x \in \alpha) \ (\forall y \in x) \ (y \in \alpha) \land (\forall x, y \in \alpha) \ (x \neq y \Rightarrow x \in y \lor y \in x)$ (clearly $\Delta_0$).
I've seen it stated that sans $\mathsf{AF}$ ordinalhood is $\Delta_1$, i.e., that there is an equivalent $\Sigma_1$ characterization to the $\Pi_1$ one given above. What may that be?

“I’ve seen it stated…” where?

@spaceisdarkgreen In Noah Schweber's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054207/positive-logical-definition-of-finiteness?rq=1

That says “using the hereditary transitive definition of ordinal”. That definition is not equivalent to the correct definition without foundation. Being an ordinal is not $\Delta_1$ without foundation. (e.g. BAFA has way too many transitive sets for this to be absolute for transitive models.)

@spaceisdarkgreen I see... (It did seem weird to me.) So without Foundation being an ordinal is just $\Pi_1$? Does that mean that statements like "is a limit ordinal," "is $\omega$," "belongs to $\omega$," etc. are too $\Pi_1$? If so, does "being finite" turn just $\Pi_1$ sans Foundation too?

Yes, all of those are $\Pi_1\setminus \Sigma_1$ in ZF - regularity. For finiteness, the same basic counterexample works: Boffa implies there are transitive non-$\omega$ models, so all the fake natural numbers would be finite in those transitive models, but infinite in the universe. (And also, the model's $\omega$ would not be the universe's... you can see a counterexample to $\Sigma_1$-ness for pretty much everything you suggested in this one example.)

@spaceisdarkgreen I see... This complicates things, then. I'm attempting to prove that working under the theory $\mathsf{ZF}^- \mathop{+}$ "the class $A$ of all atoms is countable" $\mathop{+} \forall x \ (x \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow (\exists y \in x) \ (y \cap x = \emptyset \lor y = {y}))$ one has that $(HOAD, \in) \models$ "$A$ is infinite" (where $HOAD$ is the class of all hereditarily ordinal-atom-definable sets). My previous attempt just used that finiteness (hence infiniteness) was $\Delta_1$ (which would be true if we weren't working without $\mathsf{AF}$), but I can't use that now.
