# How to show that Second Order Logic is more expressive than Weak Second Order Logic

Tags: first-order-logic, higher-order-logic

Im following the definitions from the book Mathematical Logic by Ebbinghaus.

**Definition of Second Order Logic**

[image]

**Definition of Weak Second Order Logic**

[image]

**Definition of 'Expressiveness'**

[image]

I'm trying to show that $\mathscr{L}_{\rm II}^w \leq \mathscr{L}_{\rm II}$. To do this, by the above definitions we need to show that for every symbol set $S$ and sentence $\phi\in L_{\rm II}^w(S)$, there is a sentence $\psi\in L_{\rm II}(S)$ such that ${\rm Mod}^S_{\mathscr{L}_{\rm II}^w}(\phi) = {\rm Mod}^S_{\mathscr{L}_{\rm II}}(\psi)$, i.e., for all $S$-structure $\mathfrak{A}$ we have that
$\mathfrak{A}\vDash_{\mathscr{L}_{\rm II}^w} \phi$ iff $\mathfrak{A}\vDash_{\mathscr{L}_{\rm II}} \psi$.

I thought about by induction on the structure of $\phi$ because if $\phi \equiv \exists X\phi'$, then

\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{A}\vDash_{\mathscr{L}_{\rm II}^w} \exists X\phi' & \text{ iff there is a finite $C\subseteq A^n$ such that } \mathfrak{A}_{\frac{C}{X}}\vDash_{\mathscr{L}_{\rm II}^w} \phi' 
 \qquad (\text{by definition})\\
 &  \text{ iff there is a finite $C\subseteq A^n$ such that } \mathfrak{A}_{\frac{C}{X}}\vDash_{\mathscr{L}_{\rm II}} \psi' \qquad (\text{by I.H.})\\
& \Rightarrow \mathfrak{A}\vDash_{\mathscr{L}_{\rm II}} \exists X\psi'.
\end{align*}

The problem is when we try to prove the converse since $\mathfrak{A}\vDash_{\mathscr{L}_{\rm II}} \exists X\psi'$ provides us an arbitrary subset $C\subseteq A^n$ that may not be finite.

Answer (score 1):

The translation is indeed slightly more complicated than what you're setting up.

The point is that SOL can express that a given set is finite$^1$. This lets us set up the quantifier clause for our translation as $$(\exists X\varphi)'=\exists X[X\mbox{ is finite}\wedge \varphi'].$$

---

$^1$This actually has a slight subtlety. **If** we assume the axiom of choice, then "$X$ is finite" is equivalent to "$X$ has no non-surjective self-injection" (called *Dedekind-finiteness*), which is clearly SOL-expressible. On the other hand, it's consistent with set theory without choice that there are Dedekind-finite infinite sets. So if we want an approach that works without the axiom of choice, more care is needed. Since this is a cute puzzle, I've spoilered a solution:

> "$X$ is finite" is equivalent to "There is a binary relation on $X$ which is both a well-ordering and a co-well-ordering." Alternatively, you could just say "$X$ is Dedekind-finite and well-orderable." (If you're interested in the complexity of choiceless characterizations finiteness, see the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765978/the-complexity-of-finiteness).)